# ObjectId is not being matched with string in graphLookup mongodb nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, mean-stack

My collection is below

```
const schema=Schema({
name: { type: String, required: true,maxlength:50 },
subcategory: [{ type: String, required: true,maxlength:100 }],
isActive: { type: Boolean, required: true ,default: 1},
```

});

I inserted data like this

```
{
        "subcategory": [
            "5da084d13a61194bd4982947"
        ],
        "isActive": true,
        "_id": "5da084cb3a61194bd4982946",
        "name": "drinks",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "subcategory": [],
        "isActive": true,
        "_id": "5da084d13a61194bd4982947",
        "name": "coke",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "subcategory": [],
        "isActive": true,
        "_id": "5da084d63a61194bd4982948",
        "name": "fanta",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

Now I am trying to get graphLookup on "subcategory" with "_id" like below

```
 {
            $graphLookup: {
                from: 'category', // Use the customers collection
                startWith: '$subcategory', // Start looking at the document's `friends` property
                connectFromField: 'subcategory', // A link in the graph is represented by the friends property...
                connectToField: '_id', // ... pointing to another customer's _id property
                maxDepth: 1, // Only recurse one level deep
                as: 'connections' // Store this in the `connections` property
            }
        }
```

but it does not give me result in "connection" field within pipline. It gives reult like this

```
{
        "_id": "5da084cb3a61194bd4982946",
        "subcategory": [
            "5da084d13a61194bd4982947"
        ],
        "isActive": true,
        "name": "drinks",
        "__v": 0,
        "connections": []
    },
    {
        "_id": "5da084d13a61194bd4982947",
        "subcategory": [],
        "isActive": true,
        "name": "coke",
        "__v": 0,
        "connections": []
    },
```

you can see there is nothing in connections. It is empty.

Comment: Hmm, this query works perfectly for me. Are you sure your collection is named 'category'? https://mongoplayground.net/p/ECF5phjDz8t

Comment: yes I named it category in my node js code but in mongodb its name is categories so I think I should use "category" not categories

Comment: category.aggregate([
            {
                $graphLookup: {
                    from: "categories",
                    startWith: "$subcategory",
                    connectFromField: "subcategory",
                    connectToField: "_id",
                    maxDepth: 0,
                    as: "connections"
                }
            }
        ]).then(function (data) {
            var arr={message:"success",data:data}
            callback(arr);
        });

Comment: I am using this code. It works online as you sent link but not working on my local system. My db version is 4

Comment: what is 'category' in  node js? (category.aggregate...)